# How will I transform my data to a wavelet?

Tags: time-series, wavelets

I have just started studying wavelets, but there's a fundamental problem. The writer constantly speaks about transformations of a function x(.), but in practice I just have a series of data and not a function, so how will I transform them into a wavelet?

Let's say my sample size is 100.  How do I transform it to a Haar wavelet in theory?

Comment: You are just operating on a space of sequences instead of a space of functions. What software are you using?

Comment: I use RStudio and eviews, but my concern is how does the R functions work mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [discrete wavelet transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_wavelet_transform).